# Equivalent of segfault on Windows/MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, visual-studio-2019

On Linux, the following code:

```
long* p = (long*)reinterpret_cast<void*>(0x634963963496034) // random memory address
std::cout << *p;
```

will likely cause a read of memory that hasn't been allocated, and the program will raise a SIGSEGV signal.  Otherwise known as a segfault.  (An action can be attached via `sigaction(2)`).

Is there an equivalent mechanism on Windows / MSVC ?

What will the above code do on Windows?  Is there any way to trap this memory access violation, and run a user-provided function?

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, when catching the exception using [Structured Exception Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/structured-exception-handling), the macro [GetExceptionCode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/getexceptioncode) will return `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`.

It is also possible to use C++ exception handling to catch SEH exceptions, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/exception-handling-differences).

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for was `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`.  `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` on Windows is equivalent to `sigaction` on Linux for this use case.